# After installation, blank screen from Reportico

Tags: php, iis, reporting, reportico

I've installed [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/site/index.php) in /reportico under my website root. I set permissions for the folders `template_c`, `projects` and `projects/admin` to READ_&_EXECUTE, LIST_FOLDER_CONTENTS, READ, and WRITE for the user `IIS_IUSRS`. I've had PHP 5.3.28 running for months with the PDO extension working just fine, so no problems there.

When I browse to:

http://mywebsite/reportico/index.php

...it immediate forwards to:

http://mywebsite/reportico/run.php?project=admin&execute_mode=ADMIN&clear_session=1

...and I get a blank white screen.

I looked in the PHP logs and found this:

```
[27-Apr-2015 09:06:19 America/Tegucigalpa] PHP Warning: include(templates_c\%%62^620^6206D997%%admin.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\inetpub\inventronicsusa\reportico\smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1256
[27-Apr-2015 09:06:19 America/Tegucigalpa] PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening 'templates_c\%%62^620^6206D997%%admin.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\inetpub\inventronicsusa\reportico\smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1256
```

This is my first attempt to run Reportico. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Deed, the author of the software, was very helpful; he helped me find the answer.

While the [web site](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/quickstart/installation) says:

```
...ensure that the following files and folders have write permission:-
templates_c
projects - where you will create report suites
projects/admin - for storing the Reportico admin configuration
```

...just setting **Read/Write** permission for them is not enough. The software needs the ability to delete from these folders. So, in IIS, that means you have to give it **Modify** permission in addition to the **Read/Write** permissions mentioned above.

Hope that helps someone down the line.